# I'm trying to create a simple userform that adds and deletes a block of text in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a userform with a bunch of checkboxes. I want the VBA code to add a block of text (defined as a variable) if the checkbox is true and remove that block of text if it gets unchecked. As an example, this is what I have for one of the checkboxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim Text1 As String
    Text1 = "Text test"
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Text1
    Selection.InsertParagraph
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    Selection.Delete Text:=Text1
    End If
End Sub
```

First of all, the `Selection.Delete Text:=Text1` part is completely wrong. I've tried to google something similar and have been unable to find anything that deletes the content of a variable.

Second of all, there seems to be an error with the `Selection.InsertParagraph` code. I want it to add a new paragraph between each block of text/variable, however with the way that the code is now, it adds the text block and the paragraphs separately like this if I were to activate the macro 3 times:

> Text testText testText test
>
> (new paragraph)
>
> (new paragraph)
>
> (new paragraph)

What I want instead is this:

> Text test
>
> (new paragraph)
>
> Text test
>
> (new paragraph)
>
> Text test
>
> (new paragraph)

Comment: Ideally, this question should be broken up into *two* questions: how to get the required insertion and how to delete an existing result. There is insufficient information to answer the second as you don't specify how Word should be able to identify what should be deleted. For example: should any instances of the text be removed from the document, no matter where they are? Or should only the inserted text be removed? If yes, can the user possibly call up the form again and expect to remove it at a later point? Can you work with content controls in the document? Or with bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the first question, for which there is sufficient information to provide an answer...

The best control of where something is inserted and foramtted in a Word document is to use `Range` objects. There can be only one Selection, but code can work with multiple Ranges.

For inserting a new paragraph immediately following text it's possible to append the new paragraph at the end of the text using the ANSI 13 character, which can be represented in VBA code using `vbCr`.

Example:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim Text1 As String
    Dim rngTarget as Range

    Text1 = "Text test"
    Set rngTarget = Selection.Range

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      rngTarget.Text = Text1 & vbCr
    End If
    '
    'If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    '  Selection.Delete Text:=Text1
    'End If

   '''Move to the end of the range and select that for the next iteration
    rngTarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rngTarget.Select
End Sub
```